# How do I animate child view controllers when adding to/removing from a container view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have the following 2 functions that add and remove child view controllers triggered from a container view controller:

```
@discardableResult func addChildViewController(withChildViewController childViewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
    // Add Child View Controller
    addChildViewController(childViewController)
    childViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
    // Add Child View as Subview
    view.addSubview(childViewController.view)
    // Configure Child View
    childViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    childViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    // Notify Child View Controller
    childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    return childViewController
}
@discardableResult func removeChildViewController(withChildViewController childViewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
    // Notify Child View Controller
    childViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    childViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: true)
    // Remove Child View From Superview
    childViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    // Notify Child View Controller
    childViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
    return childViewController
}
```

The functions above are extensions to UIViewController, so all I'm doing is self.addChildViewController() and self.removeChildViewController() on the parent view controller.

How do I animate the view being removed on its way out and the view being added on its way in?

Comment: Do you have multiple child controllers & try to switch in betweens Or only single one?

Comment: I have multiple child view controllers, but at any given time, I'm adding one and removing the last one.

Comment: Which animation do you want when child view controller added?

Comment: Any works as an example. Let's work with fade – so the child VC that is removed will fade out while the child VC that is added will fade in.

Answer (score 14):

Animating between different child view controllers:-

```
func cycleFromViewController(oldViewController: UIViewController, toViewController newViewController: UIViewController) {
    oldViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.addChildViewController(newViewController)
    self.addSubview(subView: newViewController.view, toView:self.containerView!)

    newViewController.view.alpha = 0
    newViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: { 
        newViewController.view.alpha = 1
        oldViewController.view.alpha = 0
    }) { (finished) in
        oldViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        oldViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
        newViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}
```

In above,

- oldViewController:- Current displayed child viewController
- newViewController:- New child view controller that will going to add
- containerView:- A view in which all child controllers are displaying.

To animate child view, you can use different type of animation style by replacing **transitionFlipFromLeft** to available **UIViewAnimationOptions** according requirement.

Comment: This is getting me somewhat close. I had to do view.addSubview(newViewController.view): self.addSubview(subView: newViewController.view, toView:self.containerView!) didn't work. With it though, the very first time my view disappears, it fades out, but then after that, my views never show.

Answer (score 12):

Answer of Sagar is not complete `addSubview` method is missing there

Here is full answer

```
func cycleFromViewController(oldViewController: UIViewController, toViewController newViewController: UIViewController) {
        oldViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addChildViewController(newViewController)
        self.addSubview(subView: newViewController.view, toView:self.containerView!)

        newViewController.view.alpha = 0
        newViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
            newViewController.view.alpha = 1
            oldViewController.view.alpha = 0
        }) { (finished) in
            oldViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
            oldViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
            newViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


   private func addSubview(subView:UIView, toView parentView:UIView) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        parentView.addSubview(subView)

        subView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        subView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        subView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        subView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor).isActive  = true
    }
```

Hope it is helpful to someone